# using canopy without GUI

Tags: python, enthought, canopy

I am using [Canopy by Enthought](https://www.enthought.com/products/canopy/). I have set the same in a debian server. I have also made a virtual environment as per the [documentation provided](http://www.docs.enthought.com/canopy/configure/canopy-cli.html#scenario-setting-up-the-user-environment-without-a-gui). What I don't understand is how t run a python script without the gui. how can this be done? i require this so that I can run daemon and switch off my terminal.

All I want to know is how to run a python script without using canopy GUI, and instead run in terminal but use the environment in canopy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You first need to activate your virtual environment using `source ~/my_venv/bin/activate`. Once the right executable is the default python executable (test with `which python`) then you can simply run from your terminal `python <NAME OF YOUR SCRIPT.py>`.